# Noise and potentiometer types

Tags: noise, potentiometer

I have a cermet [potentiometer](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/bourns-inc/3361P-1-203GLF/3361P-203GLFCT-ND/1089399) controlling the final gain of an opamp that I am using to control the amplitude of a 120kHz sine wave signal, about 2Vpp. What I have noticed, and it is a subtle effect, is that the noise in the signal is occasionally affected by the position of the wiper.

The questions are: what can I do about this? Is there a better material type? How do I test such devices for noise (which I assume comes from mechanical interface of conductor and wiper)?

Circuit diagram below

[image]

Comment: I am wondering why the potentiometer is not part of the op-amp feed back resistance instead of the op-amp's output.  This is where most control the gain and therefore the output of the op-amp.  (Also, a schematic would help us  figure out what you are up to!)

Comment: @st2000 Added diagram

Comment: I await with interest the answers. In the meantime, it's normal practice to connect the open end of the pot to the wiper. In this way there is always _some_ connection through the pot if the wiper hits a bad spot.

Comment: You are using it as feed back!  Sorry.  The way you worded it, it sounded like to put it between the op-amp and the load.

Comment: @st2000 I worded it incorrectly originally, and then revised it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contact resistance variation is 3% of the value (not great) but this could be improved by using the pot as a potential divider and feeding the wiper directly to the inverting input. The wiper feeding the inverting input means the current through the wiper is effectively zero other than op-amp bias currents (nA to pA).

So, in this new configuration, it doesn't matter so much about wiper contact resistance changes. If you had shown all your circuit including what feeds the inverting input I might have been a bit more definite about this.

EDIT this is what I recommend to try: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmPsQo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hope it works OK

Comment: The inverting pin is fed by a 10K resistor. The stage is essentially a gain control and level shifter

Comment: Try the circuit I have added to my answer Dirk.

Comment: +1 for a very nice configuration for a gain control. Not only is there near zero current in the wiper, but it also gives pseudo-log performance. Consider an R3, between the end of the pot and the amplifier output, also of 10k. Then the pot fully left is gain of 3 (+10dB), fully right is gain of 0.333 (-10dB), and it's not far off linear in dB for the whole of its rotation.

Comment: @neil, yes good idea.

Comment: @Andyaka not my idea, the BBC from the '40s or '50s. But very few people have met it, and my google foo is too weak to find it.

Comment: @DirkBruere did this circuit idea work?

Comment: @Andyaka I have not tried it yet, but it is scheduled to be used in the next revision

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is an inverting op-amp configuration.  But I don't see an input resistance as there is in this diagram:

[image]

For the above diagram we can calculate the gain using this equation:

```
Vout = Vin * (Rf/Rin)
```

But if your input resistance is zero, then the above equation doesn't work.  There is likely some resistance from the source of the signal.  But if it unpredictably changes it may distort the signal.  Try adding a known input resistance and let us know what happens.

Comment: Rin = 10K, and is not shown on my diagram